# iOS - Create views with code or by storyboard designer?

Tags: ios, xamarin

My development team and I are debating to create all our views purely by code, or to continue using the designer/storyboard. Performance is our main concern.

Most of us find it easier to code all of our views, since we don't have to use constraints this way (which is tedious for us). But our main concern is performance. Will one option have greater performance than the other? And is there any other reason why you would choose one over the other?

We're using Xamarin.iOS if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1):

This is a question that is very opinion based and has been discussed at length in previous questions, like here:

[Speed of iOS development using Storyboards vs programatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11113773/speed-of-ios-development-using-storyboards-vs-programatically)

[Storyboards vs. doing it in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17510569/storyboards-vs-doing-it-in-code)